# Как получить координаты мыши в обработчике события

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter

Как при событии(bind) в функции-исполнителе взять координаты курсора мышки на момент события(x и y)?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22925599/mouse-position-python-tkinter

Answer (score 0, accepted):

В обработчик события передается объект event, в нем находится информация о событии, которое произошло, в том числе координаты мыши:

```
import tkinter as tk

root = tk.Tk()

def test(event):
    print(event)
    print(event.x, event.y)

root.bind('<Button-1>', test)

root.mainloop()
```

Пример вывода:

```
<ButtonPress event state=Mod2 num=1 x=167 y=79>
167 79
<ButtonPress event state=Mod2 num=1 x=152 y=142>
152 142
<ButtonPress event state=Mod2 num=1 x=110 y=163>
110 163
<ButtonPress event state=Mod2 num=1 x=94 y=100>
94 100
<ButtonPress event state=Mod2 num=1 x=158 y=102>
158 102
<ButtonPress event state=Mod2 num=1 x=140 y=169>
140 169
```